# Google cloud texttospeech "has no attribute 'SynthesisInput'" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries?hl=pt-br#client-libraries-install-python

While trying the main Google example, I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-866a7868dbb4> in <module>
     10 
     11 # Set the text input to be synthesized
---> 12 synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")
     13 
     14 # Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml

AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.texttospeech' has no attribute 'SynthesisInput'
```

Any sugestions?
Using conda-forge: google-cloud-texttospeech 1.0.1

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example using the same library (google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1) and it also fails. The fix for this is to just simply update your library to the latest version (2.3.0) using `!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-texttospeech`  and your code snippet will work.

Error when using the outdated 1.0.1 version.

[image]

For testing purposes I included printing of the encoded response.
[image]